# From an array, get all indexes of sub-arrays where all elements are true

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is an example of an array I can have:

```
let testArray = [
  [true, true, false],
  [false, true, false],
  [true, true, true],
  [false, true, false],
  [true, true, true]
]
```

How can I check if all the values in a sub-array are `true` and then get all indexes of sub-arrays which pass the check?

Comment: I have tried using **every** method, but I don't know how to use index, and I am not sure that this method is providing me with the result I need.

Comment: "get the index of the element" What element do you mean?

Comment: In this example, I should get an index of 2, since the third element in the array has all true value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create objects that hold the `index` and a boolean whether all sub-array elements are `true` (with [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and `Boolean` as the callback), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select only those where all elements are `true`, then another `map` to get only the indexes.

```js
let testArray = [
  [true, true, false],
  [false, true, false],
  [true, true, true],
  [false, true, false],
  [true, true, true]
];
console.log(testArray
  .map((subArray, index) => ({
    index,
    allTrue: subArray.every(Boolean)
  }))
  .filter((entry) => entry.allTrue)
  .map((entry) => entry.index));
```

Comment: This is partially working - the function will log just the first match, and I all indexes.

Comment: @JonasW. Sure, but this creates a new function at every iteration of `findIndex`. Placing an existing function in there is more elegant.

Comment: @Sasha You said “index of the element”, not “elements”, and “index of that array”, not “those arrays”.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :/. I am trying to tweak your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the outer array by checking the inner array and take the index or nothing.

```js
var array = [[true, true, false], [false, true, false], [true, true, true], [false, true, false]],
    allTrue = array.reduce((r, a, i) => r.concat(a.every(Boolean) ? i : []), []);

console.log(allTrue);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for. You misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Héctor, i think i got it.